# Css layout - overlapping divs

Tags: css, layout, html, sticky-footer, overlapping

I have a really stuburn layout, that I just can not resolve ..

```
- Left column - Fixed,Static (always in view)
- Right column - Fluid/liquid/scrollable
--- Header - fixed 
--- left/main fluid/liquid
--- Right/sidebar - fixed width
--- footer
```

(if the above is not clear - header,left/main,right/sidebar,footer are INSIDE the right column)

now, this layout sort of working ,

```
<div id="left-col">left col</div>

<div id="container">

    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
        main
    </div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>

#left-col {
    width: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    background: yellow;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#container {
    margin-left: 50px;
    background: black;
}
#header {
    background: green;
}
#main {
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
}
#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 50px;
    background: pink;
}
#footer {
    background: red;
}
```

but still I have one annoying problem - 
when the main content is not long enough - the sidebar and the footer are overlapping ..
That is because the sidebar is : absolute positioned - but then again, If i make it relative, and the page is being re-sized, the sidebar goes UNDER the main ... (not enough space for fluid ...)
so , my question is this , 
Anyone has an Idea how to keep the footer UNDER the sidebar ? (jQuery sticky tricks not working, and CSS tricks are quite tricky here..)
 or any other ides to achieve this layout ?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/VNU6Z/

Comment: A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would help lots.

Comment: thanks Kyle and Robert for answering - but JSFIddle , as much as it seems a nice toy , does not produce accurate results. in fact, the layouts proposed here WORK on JSFiddle - but not on the browser itself (checked in ie6-7-8)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use float:right instead of position absolute

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Uruqw/)

Answer (score 1):

Kim is right.  Make `div id="sidebar"` **float:right**, and make `div id="main"` **overflow:hidden**

`div id="main"` will then resize to your floated elements as though it had **float:left**

Comment: thanks for the answer , I had some leftovers from css experimenting that caused all the problems .. anyhow , I have checked your solution in all the browsers I usually confirm, and ie6 (as usuall) is not really getting it ... anyhow, you pointed me in the right direction. I just will have to finally start dropping ie6 support. hey, if microsoft does not care about us, why should we care about them , right ?

Comment: well - I am sorry, but I need to update something . this is NOT working in IE - the main frame goes UNDER the left-col if given some height. I am begining to think it is almost impossiable to get a cross browser layout like that .